Python keras functional api training with tf.data.dataset.prefetch() for validation causes error
While running a multi-input model with validation data my kaggle notebook runs into an AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'items' error. I could not find proper documentation or guides on how to use repeat() for validation_data in model.fit(), however, it work fine with only training_dataset.
Expected fit to output history object. Received from File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/backend/tensorflow/trainer.py:354, in TensorFlowTrainer.fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_batch_size, validation_freq):
    (...)
    353     val_logs = {
--> 354         "val_" + name: val for name, val in val_logs.items()
    355     }
    (...)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'items' 
``` from val_logs.items() part

